# For what $z \arcsin(z)$ is real number?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For what $z\arcsin(z)$ will be a real number?
I tried to discover function $\sin(z)$ and find all 
$$z = a + b\cdot i: \sin(z) = Re \Rightarrow \arcsin(z) = Re.$$
But, of course, it's not correctly. 
From wolframalpha I found that for 
$$z>1 \quad \arcsin(z) = a + b\cdot i.$$ 
How to prove it?
Are there any other restrictions for $z$? For example, must z be only real number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\sin ^{-1}(z)=a$, where a is a real number, $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Then
$$\sin(\sin ^{-1}(z))=\sin (a)=z$$ again where a is real. So $z\in [-1,1]$.